# Is there a shortcut to edit thousands of excel formulas?

Tags: excel

I want to change references in formulas, from

```
=IF(N14="YES","A","B")
```

to

```
=IF($N$14="YES","A","B")
```

Fine on a single cell, my problem is that I have 20 x 1000 cells to edit like this. Is there a quick way to do it?

I don't think find and replace can be applied, as both row and column change (to be edited formulas spread over 20 rows and 1000 columns), so in the best case I need to do it 20+1000 times.

Comment: Are you open to VBA solution?

Comment: yes, if nothing else is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the desired range and run this code.

```
Sub RelativeToAbsolute()
    Dim c As Variant
    For Each c In Selection
        If c.Formula <> "" Then
            c.Value = Application.ConvertFormula(c.Formula, xlA1, , xlAbsolute)
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: @L.Dutch - You can even enter the range in code by adding following two lines
`Dim Selection As Range 
Set Selection = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F10")`
before for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Find and Replace. Find `N14`, Replace with `$N$14`, Look in `Formulas`.

If that does not fit the situation, edit your question and explain the situation in more detail, then post a comment.

Comment: More explanation added. I don't think find and replace can apply.

Comment: depending on your the exact thing that needs replacing and what exists in your formula, the replace all button can be very powerful... can save you time by quickly editing, or it can screw up a lot of formulas fast.  You need to be very aware of what can and cannot be replaced.  it does fit some situation.